# Google Protocol Buffers 3 Builders in C#

Tags: c#, protocols, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, proto

I am developing a game in unity3d. I am using google's protocol buffer `3.6.1` compiler to compile .proto files in c#. but its not creating its builders. does builders removed ?

whats the new way to create a request message in csharp.Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The current version prefers regular POCO style over builders (albeit generated POCOs with utility code in them). Just treat them as regular .NET types:

```
var msg = new SomeMessageType { SomeInteger = 42, SomeString = "hello" };
```

Comment: Thank You @Marc. One more thing to ask. if i use protocol buffer 3.0.0 it should create builders ? is there any way to create builders ?

Comment: @FaisalImran AFAIK there is no builder API in the current version; allow me to turn the question around: what is it that you want to do with a builder, that you can't already do with the POCO API?

Comment: I have a project that uses older version (3.0.0). i just want to update some calls. You are right POCO API can do that but i don't want to rewrite all. that's why i want to know how to create builders ?

Comment: @FaisalImran I'm unable to find any reference to builders for csharp in either the docs or the github source of protoc; I'm **not** an authoritative source on Google's implementation, though